# How can I positioning an image to the value of the progress bar only with CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I use the blue circle as a value of the progress bar with only using CSS?
The progress bar itself is only 2 pixel height, and the circle that represents the value of the progress bar is much bigger.

```css
.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

progress {
  background-color: #9da29b;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #9da29b;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #f01010;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #9da29b;
}

#this-is-not-that-i-want {
  background-color: #9da29b;
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

#this-is-not-that-i-want::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #f01010;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 30px) center, black 15px, lightgreen 15px);
}

#this-is-not-that-i-want::progress-value {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 30px) center, black 15px, lightgreen 15px);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>

<progress id="it-is-smaller-than-the-circle" value="60" max="100"></progress>

<progress id="this-is-not-that-i-want" value="60" max="100"></progress>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mg5Lvx5z/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use :after to create a psuedo element inside the progress bar, then position it to the progress level.

```
#it-is-smaller-than-the-circle::-webkit-progress-value {position: relative;}
#it-is-smaller-than-the-circle::-webkit-progress-value:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mg5Lvx5z/2/

Comment: I wanted that blue circle on that position where the red line ends. Like a range input that has red line in the left and gray in the right and the circle is a blue circle.

Comment: I want to have something like this without any JS. http://jsfiddle.net/JnrvG/561/